# Android Studio crashed | now what option do I have ?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-studio

I created a service file , and tried to call it using startService() , however it underlined it with red color, so I deleted that service file, and created it again. I repeated this twice, and after Android Studio says internal IDE error. Now I am not able to create an Activity or Java Class. Also not able to start the emulator as well. Studio tells me to submit a bug report. I did . And now what other possible solutions do I have to fix my IDE ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete Android Studio user data (.AndroidStudio) and reinstall Android SDK

Comment: Where is it located ? I mean user data ?

Comment: If you are using Windows, it's located at C:\Users\USERNAME\.AndroidStudio , and the Android SDK is where you have installed it